# download several files to tablet from drive

Tags: tablet, downloading, files, google-drive

I would like to download approx. 100 pictures from [google-drive](/questions/tagged/google-drive) to my tablet.
I found only one way, only one picture by one. 
Is there a way to "download all"?

Answer (score 1):

[From this page you can zip and download all Drive files](https://web.archive.org/web/20140322155357/http://www.doiteasily.com/2012/04/download-all-google-drive-google-docs.html)

> Google drive has the ability to download a bunch of files and folders in a zip file.
>
> To do so , just select the files and folders and select `More > Download > Download from Google Drive`
>
> The files will be zipped and it will take some time for the process depending upon the size of the files and folders. You can either wait with that window open by looking into the estimated time or you can click 'Email when ready' which will send you a email with link to zip file onces its done.

Note the max zip size is 2Gb.

An alternative would be to do the following:

Sync the files to your computer using the google drive client app:

1. Install the google drive app on your computer
2. On drive.google.com, drag the folder shared with you from "Shared with me" to "My Drive"
3. Now all the files should automagically appear on the "Google drive" folder on your computer

Comment: As I understand, you describe actions taken on PC.

Comment: @user55150 Is there no option in the app, the first way was SUPPOSED to be the app, and the other for your PC if it is quicker. Ok, I've added a third option, from the Play store, hopefully ONE of these will work!

Comment: My question belongs to working with a tablet. On the tablet I open the Google Drive app, see my files and cannot find the option as "mark all" or "download all". Thanks for help.

Comment: @user55150 try the app I linked to. I know it is with the tablet, but if there is NO option (and the app doesn't work) then you may HAVE to do it on a PC or one by one. I'm trying to find a way to get your files over for you, unfortunately Drive doens't make it easy (one of MANY reasons I would never, ever use Google Drive tbh). Try the app and let me know. Fingers crossed!!